# why is this parallel process not writing output to files but printing to console instead?

Tags: output, gnu-parallel

Disclaimer: This is a more general question of the one [I asked on biostars.org](https://www.biostars.org/p/254532/) about parallel and writing to file.

When I run a program ([`obisplit` from `obitools` package](http://metabarcoding.org/obitools/doc/scripts/obisplit.html)) sequentially, it reads one file and creates a number of files based on some criterion (not important here) in the original file:

```
input_file.fastq
     |____ output_01.fastq
     |____ output_02.fastq
     |____ output_03.fastq
```

However, when I split the input file and run them in parallel (version from ubuntu repo: 20141022),

```
find . * | grep -P "^input_file" | parallel -j+3 obisplit -p output_{/.}_ -t variable_to_split_on {/}
```

I would expect to get files

```
input_file_a.fastq
     |____ output_input_file_a_01.fastq
     |____ output_input_file_a_02.fastq
     |____ output_input_file_a_03.fastq
input_file_b.fastq
     |____ output_input_file_b_01.fastq
     |____ output_input_file_b_02.fastq
     |____ output_input_file_b_03.fastq
input_file_c.fastq
     |____ output_input_file_c_01.fastq
     |____ output_input_file_c_02.fastq
     |____ output_input_file_c_03.fastq
```

but the output is only printed to console.

Is there something inherent in `parallel` which causes this printing to console or could this be the way `obisplit` is behaving for whatever reason? Is there a way to convince each core commandeered by `parallel` to print to a specific file instead of the console?

Comment: Does `parallel --dry-run` output what you expect to be run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound as if `obisplit` behaves differently if output is redirected.

You can ask GNU Parallel to output to files:

```
seq 10 | parallel --results output_{} echo this is input {} >/dev/null
```

(or if your version is older:

```
seq 10 | parallel echo this is input {} '>' output_{}
```

)

It will create `output_#`,`output_#.err`,`output_#.seq`.

Comment: Sorry to have wasted your time, but your comment under my question nudged me into the right direction. I did a dry run and actually ran one part of the output and it was outputting into the console. This got me thinking and upon closer inspection, I was calling the wrong .fastq file :facepalm:. When the right file was called, things folded into place nicely. Thank you for this wonderful tool, it's saving me temporal tonnes of time.